# How to ignore the <br> tag xpath

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, web-scraping

```
myList = tree.xpath('//div[@id="RM1127"]/div[@class="moreInfo"]/text()')
```

I'm scraping a website for elements inside this div. It works fine but on this one div, there's a `<b>` tag. myList returns elements for that div as two separate elements.

```
<div class="moreInfo" style="display:none;font-weight:normal; font-size:14px; margin-top:6px; padding:0px 0 0 30px;">

    Over ½ lb. of jumbo shrimp fried golden crisp in a…

    <br></br>

    coleslaw, cocktail & Tartar sauce. …

</div>
```

The html looks like this. Instead of having 'Over ½ lb. of jumbo shrimp fried golden crisp in a' and 'coleslaw, cocktail & Tartar sauce' together as one element, I'm getting them both as separate elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python `XPath + LXML`, just invoke `HtmlElement.text_content()`. Take a look on this full exemple:

```
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html    

html  ="""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="RM1127">
        <div class="moreInfo" style="">

            Over 1/2 lb. of jumbo shrimp fried golden crisp in a...

            <br>

            coleslaw, cocktail & Tartar sauce

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>"""

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tags = dom.xpath("""//div[@id="RM1127"]/div[@class="moreInfo"]""")

for e in tags:
    print(e.text_content())
```

**From [doc](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):**

> **lxml.html.HtmlElement.text_content():**
>       Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.

Comment: I can't so this with the link directly:

from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.dinein.co.uk/108/restaurant/N1-islington/french-delivery/la-petite-auberge.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

mainCourse = tree.xpath('//div[@id="RM1127"]/div[@class="m01"]/text()')
for e in mainCourse:
print(e.text_content())

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: '_ElementStringResult' object has no attribute 'text_content'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath expression:

```xml
string(//div[@id="RM1127"]/div[@class="moreInfo"])
```

When applied to a node-set, the XPath [string function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) returns the string-value of the node that is first in document order. The string-value of an element node is the [concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes).

Comment: @nnwellnhof how do i use this to apply it to all ids?

Comment: @K.B If you're looking for a single XPath expression that returns a set of strings, that's not possible with lxml (XPath 1.0). Try felipsmartins solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

If using scrapy and dont want to use lxml.html then I couldnt find any other way than using regex to remove such br tags.
[scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.replace)
`response = response.replace(body = re.sub(b'</?\s*\s*br\s*/?\s*>',b'',response.body))`
Anyone having any better ways please do share.